# How to run Windows SDK Command Prompt from command line?

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, sdk

I have instruction to run

> Select Start --> All Programs --> Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1 and open
>   Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt.

which is obsolete for Windows 8.1

I have installed something named "Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1" from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx, but didn't get application icon mentionned.

How to find executable for SDK command prompt and run it from command line?

Comment: Why do you need this? what do you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this Microsoft web page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx)...

> The Windows SDK no longer ships with a complete command-line build environment. You must install a compiler and build environment separately.

Translating that from Microsoft-ese to English, that means "We would really love it if you would just buy Visual Studio 2013 now."

In recent years, Microsoft has moved away from the command prompt and Win32 development in favor of PowerShell and .NET.

Comment: So, what to do?

Comment: As the article states, you would have to install some other build environment.  There are [numerous free and paid ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments), depending on what language you code in.  Since the SDK is just a set of headers and libraries, it shouldn't be too difficult to integrate it into whatever IDE you choose.

Answer (score 1):

In Win8.1 hit the Windows-button and type "Windows SDK 7.1 Co..." (you are searching for it) until you see "Windows SDK 7.1 Command prompt" in the menu to the right. Right-click on it and choose "Run as administrator"

Comment: Where does the OP ask about running as "Administrator"?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. OP doesn't ask that.